# I cannnot import numpy

Tags: numpy

I have installed Anaconda on my computer and I can see that the numpy packages are installed but when I try to import numpy while using jupyter notebook. I am using Python version 3.9.13 and numpy version 1.21.5 and I got the error messages below;

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 fig = plt.figure()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
type here
```

Comment: Are you sure you started the notebook using a conda environment with numpy? How did you start jupyter? How did you install jupyter?

Comment: From my Anaconda navigator, I clicked on environment, left clicked on the arrow in python environment and then open it with jupyter notebook. It's working now because I did run pip install numpy in the Jupiter notebook code cell.